# Different probability for ranges of random numbers

Tags: javascript, random, distribution, probability

I'm looking for the best way of implementing random number generator, that will allow me to have control over probability from what range the generated number will be returned. To visualize what I'm trying to achieve I have a picture :

[image: not uniform random distribution]

So to summarize :
Let's say that my range is 400. At the beginning I'd like to have 5% probability of getting number 0-20. But at some moment in time I'd like to have this probability increased up to 50%. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I'd expect that getting a number in the range 0-20 is 5% by default. Increasing it to 50% just means asking for a number in the range 0-20 every second time, and 21-400 the other times. What have you got so far?

Comment: just looking for an idea. Okay but what if I want it to be 16% for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, working on your original I had a pretty simple algorithm to generate ranges in an array in the appropriate proportion, then randomly select a range and generate a random number within that range. No doubt it can be optimised if necessary, but it works for me.

It looks like a lot of code, but 3/4 of it is comments, test data and function, the actual *randomRange* function is only 17 lines of code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function randomRange(dataArray) {

  // Helper function
  function getRandomInRange(s, f) {
    return (Math.random() * (f-s+1) | 0) + s
  }

  // Generate new data array based on probability
  var i, j = dataArray.length;
  var oArray = [];
  var o;
  while (j--) {
    o = dataArray[j];

    // Make sure probability is an integer
    for (i=0, iLen=o.probability|0; i<iLen; i++) {  
      oArray.push([o.rangeStart, o.rangeEnd]);
    }
  }

  // Randomly select a range from new data array and
  // generate a random number in that range
  var oEnd = oArray.length;
  var range = oArray[getRandomInRange(0, oArray.length - 1)]; 
  return getRandomInRange(range[0], range[1]);
}

// Test data set. Probability just has to be
// representative, so 50/50 === 1/1
var dataArray = [
  {
    rangeStart: 0, 
    rangeEnd  : 20,
    probability: 1
  },
  {
    rangeStart: 21, 
    rangeEnd  : 400,
    probability: 1
  }
];

// Test function to show range and number is randomly
// selected for given probability
function testIt() {
  var el0 = document.getElementById('div0');
  var el1 = document.getElementById('div1');
  function run() {
    var n = randomRange(dataArray);
    if (n <= 20) {
      el0.innerHTML += '*';
    } else {
      el1.innerHTML += '*';
    }
  }
  setInterval(run, 500);
}


</script>

<button onclick="testIt();">Generate random number</button>

<div>Numbers 0 - 20</div>
<div id="div0"></div>
<div>Numbers 21 - 400</div>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: There is missing a semicolon ; after var dataArray = [...]  (if you are using code-minification). But this is great man! Thanks very much for sharing this.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like what you're looking for is a way to generate numbers on a normal (or Gaussian) distribution (take a look at [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) if you don't know what that means).

The [Box-Muller transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) can be used to generate pairs of normally distributed numbers.

Here is a c++ implementation of the polar form of the Box-Muller transformation that shouldn't be hard to translate to javascript.

```
// Return a real number from a normal (Gaussian) distribution with given
// mean and standard deviation by polar form of Box-Muller transformation
double x, y, r;
do
{
    x = 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
    y = 2.0 * rand() - 1.0;
    r = x * x + y * y;
}
while ( r >= 1.0 || r == 0.0 );
double s = sqrt( -2.0 * log(r) / r );
return mean + x * s * stddev;
```

Where mean is the mean of the normal distribution and stddev is the Standard Deviation of the distribution. This code is from a MersesenneTwister C++ class that I've been using recently that you can find [on Rick Wagner's page](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wagnerr/MersenneTwister.html). You can find some more useful information about the Box-Muller transformation on [this page](http://www.taygeta.com/random/gaussian.html).

Comment: at first sight looks like just the thing I was looking for.