# Generate a random number with bias result in PHP

Tags: php

I am currently in the process of coding a points system for a website I maintain, and with that I would like to award my users a random amount of points daily.

This is what I am thinking

```
[0-25] has a 75% chance 
[26 - 51] has a 13% chance
[52 - 76] has a 6% chance
[77 - 115] has a 4% chance
[115 - 200 ] has a mere 2% chance
```

So, the point bracket 0-25 has the 75% chance of being generated, so is most likely to be the one that is made.

If anyone has any ideas, or suggestions, it would be awesome to hear them.

So, basically I want a random number generated, 1-200 and I want 0-25 to have a much higher chance that 115-200.

Comment: looking for the same thing :D for now i am doing arrays for each division and a one rand to select a division then a second to select a number within the chosen division

Comment: but i don't get your percentages :S, the sum should be 100% no?

Comment: This is just how I would like to have it, the percentages are sure to change however its like a currency system, I don't want it to be very easy to gain from 115-200 credits really easily, id like it to be a rare occurence!

Comment: How does one element occur 80% of the time, while another occurs at 50% of the time, and be mutually exclusive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to bias a random number generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858364/how-to-bias-a-random-number-generator)

Comment: Just seen the mistake I have made with the percentages, I have edited them to suit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025252/different-probability-for-ranges-of-random-numbers

Comment: In your code block you say that 0-25 is 75%, then later you decide that it's 80%. How about you go away, make up your mind, then come back.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I changed the code block to make the percentages suit. Not much of a biggie..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not a biggie considering when I originally posted it the post was not contradictory, its late and I forgot all about changing the other values in the post after I edited the percentages.

Comment: @JakeBall: Well it's contradictory now. Please fix it using the "edit" button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First generate a random number between 0 and 99. Then generate a second random number in the range picked by the first.

```
$ranges = Array(
    Array(0,25,75), // [0-25] on 75% chance
    Array(26,51,13),
    Array(52,76,6),
    Array(77,115,4),
    Array(115,200,2)
);
$sel = rand(0,99);
do {
    $pick = array_shift($ranges);
    $sel -= $pick[2];
} while($pick && $sel >= 0);
$random = rand($pick[0],$pick[1]);
```

Comment: and exactly what i suggested :)