# How can I sort elements by percentage?

Tags: php

I currently have 6 users with phone numbers that are randomly displayed on a page.

We now have contest going on and I need to implement a different approach for the first three to have percentage chances to be displayed ahead like below:

1st: 35% 
2nd: 25% 
3rd: 15% 
and the rest randomly allocated. (8.33 % each).

I have tried different ways to do this, but every time I encounter different problems.

The below code is where I'm left off now and the problem with it is when an user is already extracted (added to $already_extracted), the foreach loop will go further a step and display the next user (and that gives him bigger chances).

If I break the loop to avoid this and reroll the random number in case of an extracted user, the script fails (maybe because the random numbers are within the same range, the loop is braked and $i is not incremented).

```
$already_extracted = []; // array to keep track of already displayed users

$1st_place = 35; //percent
$2nd_place = 25; //percent
$3rd_place = 15; //percent


$winners = array(
        "user1" => $1st_place, // 35
        "user2" => $1st_place + $2nd_place, // 60
        "user3" => $1st_place + $2nd_place, + $3rd_place // 75
    );

$losers = array( 'user4', "user5", "user6" );

$i = 0; 
do {
    $rand = mt_rand(1, 100);

    foreach($winners as $k => $v) {
        // if the random number is less than current value and the key 
        // is not already extracted (user already displayed)
        if ($rand <= $v && !in_array($k, $already_extracted)) { 
            // display/append user!!
            array_push($already_extracted, $k);
            $i++;
            break;
        } else if ($rand > $1st_place + $2nd_place, + $3rd_place && !in_array($k, $already_extracted)) {
            // if none of the winners got a chance, display one of the losers first
            shuffle($losers);
            // display/append user!
            array_push($already_extracted, $losers[0]);
            $i++;
            break;
        } 
    }

} while($i < 3);
```

Other problems I got with different approaches:

1. If I remove the already_extracted user from the $winners array and recalculate the chances, will make the $losers have more chances than the winners. I need to leave them at 8.33%.
2. If I don't remove/move the already displayed user from the array it can be displayed twice or more.

Edit: To further explain what I needed and why AterLux's answer solved my problem. 
This is for a store in which salespersons are randomly displayed on each page refresh. We now have an internal contest going on and the winners (first 3 places) must have the above mentioned percentage chances to be displayed first (on top) ahead of others, while the remaining salespersons to have an equal "leftover" chances (8.333 % in this case).

Comment: I don’t understand, what you want to “sort” here? How do the random numbers come into play?

Comment: _“and the rest randomly allocated. (8.33 % each)”_ - so for all remaining users, the exact same value for each of them - what exactly is “random” about that?

Comment: This makes very little sense. You may have to give us a much better explanation of what you are trying to do here before we can help much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a random number with bias result in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254470/generate-a-random-number-with-bias-result-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function pick_a_guy($guys) {
   $total = 0;
   foreach($guys as $name => $prob) {
     $total += $prob; // calculate total sum of probabilities 
   }
   $val = mt_rand() / (mt_getrandmax() + 1.0) * $total; // select a random number 0 <= $val < $total;
   $sum = 0;
   foreach($guys as $name => $prob) {
     $sum += $prob; // calculate the sum;
     if ($sum > $val) {
       return $name; // our random hero;
     } 
   }
}

$guys = array(
   'user1' => 35,
   'user2' => 25,
   'user3' => 15,
   'user4' => 8.3333,
   'user5' => 8.3333,
   'user6' => 8.3333 
); // It can be not percents but any relative probability

$winner1 = pick_a_guy($guys);
unset($guys[$winner1]); // remove winner from the array

$winner2 = pick_a_guy($guys);
unset($guys[$winner2]);

$winner3 = pick_a_guy($guys);
```

Comment: Beautiful! This saved me a lot of hassle and managed to easily implement it in my app. Clean and perfect, thank you so much! I'm curios to know why did you choose to use "$val = mt_rand() / (mt_getrandmax() + 1.0) * $total;" and not a simpler approach with smaller numbers?

Comment: Smaller number may give less probability to the last item. But instead all probabilities can be given in integer numbers and `mt_rand(0, $total - 1)` can be used instead