# I need to have an adjustable probability for my random image selector

Tags: javascript

I'm novice in **JavaScript** and am trying to pick a random image from a pool that I have set up. I want to change this so that instead of a 1/10 chance on everything if there was 10 items (a completely fair spread of probability), I want to make certain draws less likely than others.

For example, if there are 4 images, one of a **cat**, a **dog**, a **bird**, and one of a **fish**, I want the **fish** to be most common.

Say a *50%* chance for the **fish** to appear. Then the **bird** at *30%*, then the **cat** at *15%*, and the **dog** at *5%*. As of right now my code simply makes it *25%* for each. Any ideas?

(Here's a sample of the code, it won't show the pictures themselves as I have them saved on my computer, but I plan on having the pool pull from a link instead of a file in the future)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Random Draw</title>
<style type="text/css">
  body { font: 14px/1.3 verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; }
  h1 { font-size:1.3em; }
  h2 { font-size:1.2em; }
  a:link { color:#33c; } 
  a:visited { color:#339; }
  p { max-width: 60em; }

  /* so linked image won't have border */
  a img { border:none; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Image array
  var random_images_array = ['Strike.png', 'StrikeII.png', 'StrikeIII.png', 'StrikeIV.png', 'Burn.png', 'BurnII.png', 
  'BurnIII.png', 'BurnIV.png','Barrier.png', 'BarrierII.png', 'BarrierIII.png', 'BarrierIV.png', 
  'LifeD.png', 'LifeDII.png', 'LifeDIII.png', 'LifeDIV.png', 'Mitigate.png', 'MitigateII.png', 'MitigateIII.png', 'MitigateIV.png', 
  'Soothe.png', 'SootheII.png', 'SootheIII.png', 'SootheIV.png','FB.png', 'FBII.png', 'FBIII.png', 'FBIV.png',
  'RV.png', 'RVII.png', 'RF.png', 'RFII.png', 'RM.png', 'RMII.png', 'DA.png', 'DB.png', 'AV.png', 'IC.png', 'HTM.png',];
    
  function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
      path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
      var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
      var img = imgAr[ num ];
      var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
      document.write(imgStr); document.close();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Catclysm</h2>    
<h1>Draw Deck </h1>

<p>Reload the page to draw a random card </p>

<div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">getRandomImage(random_images_array, 'images/')</script>
</div>

<!-- For link: <a href="."> >
type="text/javascript">getRandomImage(random_images_array)</script></a>-->

<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Java* and *JavaScript* are two completely distinct languages.

Comment: Java is not JavaScipt; they're two separate languages; although you're apparently using JavaScript here. So while you may be a "*novice in Java*" that would be entirely irrelevant to the question, though I suspect it's a typo.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6025252/1169519)?

Comment: Ah, it was a typo. It autocorrected to javascript instead of javascript, I need to diable that. My apologies Edit: It did it again! Im a novice in javascript***

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a discrete probability distribution which describes the probability for each image being picked.

What you need is then a function that draws a random element (here: image index) from such a discrete distribution:

```js
/**
 * Draw a pseudorandom sample from the given discrete probability distribution.
 * The input probabilities will be normalized and do not have to sum up to one.
 */
function draw_discrete_sample(probabilities) {
    var sum = probabilities.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    var i = 0;
    for (var rand = Math.random() * sum; rand > 0; ++i) {
       rand -= probabilities[i];
    }
    return i - 1;
}

var images = ['fish', 'bird', 'cat', 'dog'];
var probabilities = [50, 30, 15, 5];
var index = draw_discrete_sample(probabilities);

console.log(images[index]);

// You would dynamically add this picture to your HTML document e.g. as follows:
var image = new Image();
image.src = '/images/' + images[index] + '.png';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but maybe explain your code some more or simplify it by using an index variable? As the OP is a novice, he could be confused because of the variable declaration in the form of `var 1, 2, 3;` and the function returning the array index directly in the array brackets like `array[function()];`.

Comment: Uh yes. This does solve my problem thank you! I have a basic idea of how the code youve given me work, enough that I should be able to implement it. There is the problem of me actually being able to route it to grab the images from my folder

Comment: @William Well, you could do `img = new Image(); img.src = "/folder/" + images[random_image_index]; document.body.appendChild(img);` - is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Titulum Good suggestion, self-documenting code is always a nice thing to have, not only for novices

Comment: I believe so? But where would that go? I feel so foolish rn cause I know its such an obvious answer and its staring me in the face but im blanking

Comment: @William Do you want the random image to be displayed on page load? Or when e.g. a button is clicked?

Comment: It doesnt matter. Reload is easier and there is no need to have a specific button

Comment: @William See updated answer. Does that help? You would need to execute this script after the <body> element has loaded, e.g. by moving the whole script block to the end of your <body>

Comment: Oh my god thank you! This is everything ive needed and I appreciate eveerything youve done here! This has been a huge help and I hope I can help like youve helped me one day